# Paypal Auto Return not sending POST data

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I just switched my Paypal settings to allow Auto Return. Now, I no longer get post data sent to my confirmation page. When I realized this, I disabled Auto Return, I still don't get data. I also enabled IPN I enabled Auto Return. It's disabled now but I still don't get any data.

I also get an error message warning me about going from a secure page to an unsecure page. If I disable Auto Return, I still get that message but it does not show up when returning from Paypal to a confirmation page on other websites that also have no SSL certificate.

How do I fix these 2 problems to allow my customers an easy return to my website and allow me to collect data about their transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 may methods provided by PayPal IPN and PDT.

If you want to use auto return then you HAVE TO use IPN to post data to your confirmation page.

Or you can use PDT because it works only with auto return on as stated by PayPal

> Please note that in order to use Payment Data Transfer, you must turn on Auto Return.

It means that in order to send data to your confirmation page on auto return you have to enable PDT and change your confirmation script a little to verify data.